WorkManager is still not initialized properly when using DelegatingWorker
My worker

@HiltWorker
class MyWorker @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted context: Context,
    @Assisted workerParams: WorkerParameters,
) : CoroutineWorker(context, workerParams) {

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        Timber.d("doWork")

        return try {
            Result.success()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Result.failure()
        }
    }

    companion object {
        fun enqueueWork(context: Context) {
            val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .build()

            val workRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<DelegatingWorker>()
                .setExpedited(OutOfQuotaPolicy.RUN_AS_NON_EXPEDITED_WORK_REQUEST)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .setInputData(VpnOnRevokeWorker::class.delegatedData())
                .build()

            WorkManager.getInstance(context)
                .enqueue(workRequest)
        }
    }
}

I use Google's DelegatingWorker to skip WorkManager configuration in Application class:

import android.content.Context
import androidx.hilt.work.HiltWorkerFactory
import androidx.work.CoroutineWorker
import androidx.work.Data
import androidx.work.ForegroundInfo
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters
import dagger.hilt.EntryPoint
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.android.EntryPointAccessors
import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

/**
 * An entry point to retrieve the [HiltWorkerFactory] at runtime
 */
@EntryPoint
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
interface HiltWorkerFactoryEntryPoint {
    fun hiltWorkerFactory(): HiltWorkerFactory
}

private const val WORKER_CLASS_NAME = "RouterWorkerDelegateClassName"

/**
 * Adds metadata to a WorkRequest to identify what [CoroutineWorker] the [DelegatingWorker] should
 * delegate to
 */
internal fun KClass<out CoroutineWorker>.delegatedData() =
    Data.Builder()
        .putString(WORKER_CLASS_NAME, qualifiedName)
        .build()

/**
 * A worker that delegates sync to another [CoroutineWorker] constructed with a [HiltWorkerFactory].
 *
 * This allows for creating and using [CoroutineWorker] instances with extended arguments
 * without having to provide a custom WorkManager configuration that the app module needs to utilize.
 *
 * In other words, it allows for custom workers in a library module without having to own
 * configuration of the WorkManager singleton.
 */
class DelegatingWorker(
    appContext: Context,
    workerParams: WorkerParameters,
) : CoroutineWorker(appContext, workerParams) {

    private val workerClassName =
        workerParams.inputData.getString(WORKER_CLASS_NAME) ?: ""

    private val delegateWorker =
        EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication<HiltWorkerFactoryEntryPoint>(appContext)
            .hiltWorkerFactory()
            .createWorker(appContext, workerClassName, workerParams)
            as? CoroutineWorker
            ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Unable to find appropriate worker")

    override suspend fun getForegroundInfo(): ForegroundInfo =
        delegateWorker.getForegroundInfo()

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result =
        delegateWorker.doWork()
}

But I still get this error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WorkManager is not initialized properly.
You have explicitly disabled WorkManagerInitializer in your manifest, 
have not manually called WorkManager#initialize at this point, 
and your Application does not implement Configuration.Provider.
at androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerImpl.getInstance(WorkManagerImpl.java:179)
at androidx.work.WorkManager$Companion.getInstance(WorkManager.kt:173)

